# Why css background not repeating

Tags: html, css, background-image

I want to repeat my image Horizontally. However, it's not repeating

My index.html page

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1e3c72 0%, #1e3c72 1%, #2a5298 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  /** Scroll bar right side in your screen **/
}

.night {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 70vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/5/5);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.surface {
  height: 140px;
  width: 200px; /* 500px; */
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/10/10);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  /*animation: moveRight 6s linear infinite;*/
}

.car {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="night">
  <div class="surface"></div>

  <div class="car">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/75" alt="Car">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how it currently looks
[image]

What is the fault? I checked articles on w3schools but as I see there are no syntax errors.

How the correct image looks like

[image: This how I wanted to look]

Comment: Which image doesn't repeat? When I converted your code into a live demo I had to substitute your image URLs for ones that resolve on the public Internet. One of them appears to be successfully repeating for me.

Comment: You have given the element on which the background image resides a width of 500px. Therefore, the image repeat ends there. You'll have to tell us more about your overall plan.

Comment: You have set the width of the element which has the background image to just 500px. We can't tell from what you've shown what should be repeating, but maybe the background image fills the 500px. Could you put the actual image where we can see it (use the SO snippet facility and the image icon).

Comment: @Quentin Image on the surface class is not repeating

Comment: @GutsyCreatives — It is repeating. I see 15-20 copies of http://placekitten.com/10/10 in the live demo. I've no idea which bit of the static screenshot it is supposed to represent.

Comment: @Quentin I edited the question and added a new image

Comment: Then, as mentioned, it's restricted by the `width` you explicitly set and won't repeat outside of that width.

Comment: @Quentin How should I specify the width then? I am trying to create a moving car with animation.

Comment: he's talking about the `width: 200px;` in the `.surface` class. drop the width. (remove that line or set it to 100%?) also specifically for your case, just create a purple div rectangle. doesn't need to be a picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had `width: 200px;` on that element (in your snippet). If you change that to `width: 100%;`, the background repeats until the right border of its parent:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1e3c72 0%, #1e3c72 1%, #2a5298 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
  /** Scroll bar right side in your screen **/
}

.night {
  height: 80vh;
  width: 70vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5rem auto;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/5/5);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.surface {
  height: 140px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/10/10);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  /*animation: moveRight 6s linear infinite;*/
}

.car {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8%;
}
```

```html
<div class="night">
  <div class="surface"></div>

  <div class="car">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/75" alt="Car">
  </div>
</div>
```